# IN operator with 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am try to get result from 2 tables but its done but when I use IN operator with 2 different WHERE statement its bring result from only 1 table.

May I know where I am mistake?

```
$search_Query = "SELECT * FROM `sys1`,`sys2` WHERE sys1.id_1 IN (705,1,7,706,707) AND sys2.id_2 IN (705,1,7,706,707)";    
    $search_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $search_Query);        
    if($search_Result){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result)){
                    $finddown = $row['display_name']; //from sys1.id_1
                    $stream_status = $row['status']; // from sys2.id_2

                     echo $finddown. " = " . $cstatus;
            }
```

Comment: Start by [reading this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. What you have here is an implicit cross join with a strange where clause that is definitely not doing what you want it to do. We can help craft the sql you need to get the results you want, but sample data and desired results will be necessary to understand enough to be helpful.

Comment: The join syntax you use is outdated for 30 years now.